# Crispy django forms results in internal server error when accessed via uwsgi

Tags: django, forms, python-3.x, nginx, uwsgi

I have a simple form in django, which I'm trying to display with [crispy forms](https://github.com/django-crispy-forms/django-crispy-forms). Django Django-1.11.1, uwsgi 2.0.15, nginx 1.10.3-1, django-crispy-forms 1.6.1.

I've installed django-crispy-forms (`sudo pip3 install django-crispy-forms`) and I've followed their documentation, setting everything up.

In the **settings.py**:

```
[...]
INSTALLED_APPS = [
[...]
crispy_forms,
]
CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK='bootstrap3'
```

In my **template**:

```
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
[...]
<form action="{{ action }}" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% crispy form %}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

The **form**:

```
class UploadForm(forms.Form):
    f = forms.FileField(label="File")
    comment = forms.CharField(max_length=255,strip=True,required=False)
```

Now, once I include `crispy_forms` to my INSTALLED_APPS, the web application just shows `Internal Server Error` (via nginx & uwsgi).

If I run it directly via `python3 manage.py runserver`, everything appears to work perfectly fine.

Did I miss a step in the configuration of uwsgi, or how else can I fix this issue?

**edit:** All uwsgi logs when this happen is:

```
--- no python application found, check your startup logs for errors ---                                                               
[pid: 22173|app: -1|req: -1/1] 10.0.2.15 () {48 vars in 823 bytes} [Wed May 10 07:35:28 2017] GET / => generated 21 bytes in 0 msecs (
HTTP/1.1 500) 2 headers in 83 bytes (1 switches on core 0)
```

This is logged for each request. Tbh I have no idea what/where my startup logs are.

**edit2:** I've followed the [official quickstart](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/WSGIquickstart.html) for the setup:

```
[uwsgi]
chdir           = /<dir>/<django_project>
module          = <django_project>.wsgi
home            = /<dir>/<virtualenv>
master          = true
processes       = 10
socket          = /<dir>/<socket>.sock
vacuum          = true
uid             = 33 # www-data
```

**edit3:** Without the `crispy_forms`, the application runs fine via uWSGI. With it in the `INSTALLED_APPS` I'm running into these problems.
I'm guessing this is an issue with the uWSGI configuration.

---

**edit4/SOLVED:** The culprit was the `home = /<dir>/<virtualenv>`, which was still in the uWSGI configuration file from when I ran all of this in a virtualenv. Removing the `home` setting resolved my issues.

Comment: did you restart the uwsgi process?

Comment: yes I did restart it, after editing the relevant files.

Comment: Can you post the contents of your uwsgi log file?

Comment: @v1k45 I've added the *log* to the question

Comment: >no python application found
this means you haven't configured uwsgi correctly, can you post your uwsgi config too?

Comment: @v1k45 I've added the uwsgi.ini file

Comment: everything seems fine to me, did you make sure uwsgi is running on python3 as well?

Comment: How do I make sure of that @v1k45?

Comment: see where uwsgi bin is located, python3 or python2 dir

Comment: @v1k45 This seems to be different for me `/usr/local/bin/uwsgi`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The culprit was the `home = /<dir>/<virtualenv>`, which was still in the uWSGI configuration file from when I ran all of this in a virtualenv.

Removing the `home` setting resolved my issues.